# Альтернативная авторизация в Pyrogram через чат-бота Телеграм

Tags: telebot, авторизация, pyrogram, telegram

Создаю юзербота на Pyrogram с управлением через чат-бота телеграм, который в свою очередь работает на PyTelegrambotApi. Создаю авторизацию через чат-бота, чтобы создавался файл сессии в Pyrogram. По сути пользователь вводит свой номер телефона чат-боту, потом код подтверждения, должен быть создан файл сессии. Добавил асинхронность, так как без неё не работает ничего. Теперь вылазит ошибка Telegram says: [400 PHONE_COED_EXPIRED] - The confirmation code has expired (caused by "auth.SignIn").

```
import telebot
import db
import asyncio

from telebot import types
from pyrogram import Client

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
user_dict = {}
class User:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.api_id = None
        self.api_hash = None
        self.number = None

auth_dict = {}
class Auth:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.number = None
        self.app = None
        self.sc = None
        self.loop = None
        self.code = None

    def sendcode(self, number):
        #async
        self.loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(self.loop)

        self.app = Client(f"users/{self.id}/{self.id}", api_id=apiid, api_hash='apihash')
        self.app.connect()
        self.number = number
        self.sc = Client.send_code(self.app, phone_number=self.number)
        self.app.disconnect()

    def signin(self, code):
        try:
            self.app.connect()
        except:
            pass
        print(self.sc.phone_code_hash)
        Client.sign_in(self.app, phone_number=self.number, phone_code_hash=self.sc.phone_code_hash, phone_code=str(self.code))
        self.app.disconnect()

        self.loop.close()
```

В самом боте Telegram я сначала спрашиваю у пользователя номер, потом вызываю функцию sendcode, затем через bot.register_next_step_handler получаю код и вызываю функцию signin

Answer (score 1):

я тоже столкнулся с необходимостью авторизацией через отдельного бота, посмотрел ваше сообщение, набросал код и тоже полезли ошибки.

Возможно вопрос уже решён, но оставлю разяснение последующим пользователям,которые захотят повторить это.

Проблемма в том, что хЭш кода авторизации можна использовать в текущем сеансе а у вас в функциях "sendcode" и "signin" приложение подключается и отключается между шагами авторизации и ето не подходит.
По этому нужно избежать отключения пока не передастся код авторизации и не произойдёт вход в учётную запись. [Наводку на суть проблеммы получил вот здесь](https://github.com/zerobias/telegram-mtproto/issues/124)

Сразу скажу, я нуб, только начал изучать питон и нашел только способ избежать отключение, сделав одну функцию (вместо 2х) и подерил её на 2 этапа с использованием переменной "menu" и её логической проверкой, чтобы ненужный код не выполнился в ненужный момент.
И заранее извиняюсь за возможный баг в передачи номера телефона аккаунта на который происходит авторизация в переменную. Там можно на прямую прописать номер и оно точно заработает. (ну есть нуб)

Также, всех кто хочет попробовать повторить данный способ, хочу предупредить - если в бота передавать чистый код авторизации с того аккаунта в который происходит авторизация (надеюсь нормально объяснил хд) - он (код авторизации) аннулируется, потому я использую лайфхак с вводом кода через пробел и он работает

Вот мой говнокод (да, я для бота использую тот же пирограм, но суть дела не меняет)(*upd спустя сутки, перепроверил код, поправил, что бы не било ошибки, тысяча извиненй, скопировал не с того тестового файла*):

```
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client, filters

api_id = 00000000
api_hash = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
bot_token = "000000:xxxxxxxxxxx"

menu = 0
phone_number = ""
sc = None

bot = Client("cp_bot", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, bot_token=bot_token)
app = Client("test_auth", api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, phone_number=phone_number)

async def auth(number):
    global api_id
    global api_hash
    global phone_number
    global sc
    global menu
    global app
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    print(number)
    if menu == 1:
        await app.connect()
        print("trying send code")
        sc = await app.send_code(phone_number=number)
        print("OK")
    elif menu == 2:
        code = number
        ch = sc.phone_code_hash
        print(ch)
        await app.sign_in(phone_number=phone_number, phone_code_hash=ch, phone_code=str(code))
        await app.disconnect()
        loop.close()

@bot.on_message(filters.command(["start"]) & filters.text)
async def command_start(client, message):
    global menu
    await message.reply_text("Старт аутентификации! Отправь номер телефона в международном формате (+1234567890)")
    menu = 1

@bot.on_message(filters.text)
async def command_start(client, message):
    global menu
    global phone_number
    global code
    if menu == 1:
        phone = message.text
        phone = phone.replace("+", "")
        if phone.isdigit():
            print(phone)
            phone_number = phone
            await auth(phone_number)
            menu = 2
            print("is ok")
            await message.reply_text("DONE!\nТеперь отправь код авторизации, с цифрами через пробел (прим. \"1 2 266\" и подобное)")
        else:
            await message.reply_text("Phone incorrect! try again")
    elif menu == 2:
        v_dig = message.text
        v_dig = v_dig.replace(" ", "") # если в бота или личку ТГ с которого производится авторизация, пересылается
# чистый код авторизации - он аннулируется, потому я использую лайфхак с вводом кода через пробел и он работает
        print(v_dig)
        if v_dig.isdigit():
            code = v_dig
            print(code)
            await auth(code)
            await message.reply_text("DONE!\nАвторизация прошла успешно!")
            menu = 0
        else:
            await message.reply_text("CODE incorrect! try again")
bot.run()
```